# Does GetObjectField() return a local reference?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Can somebody tell me if `GetObjectField()` returns a local reference? I've checked out Sheng Liang's JNI programmer's guide and it doesn't explicitly say that `GetObjectField()` returns a local reference. Instead, it simply says that it "returns the value of the field" (cf. Liang, p. 224).

Still, I'm unsure so I'd be glad if somebody could confirm that it indeed doesn't return a local reference. Because if it does, I'd have to call `DeleteLocalRef()` on it because I'm calling `GetObjectField()` lots of times.

Comment: Yes, it's a local reference. Note also that there's a `GetObjectRefType` function if you want to check the reference type.

Comment: @Michael, please correct me if I'm wrong, but "returns the value of the field" could also mean "return the class field" (not local) if the field is declared as static?

Comment: @zlakad: If the field is static one should use `GetStaticObjectField`. But in that case you probably still get a local reference to that object.

Comment: @Michael, thanks. I was referring to the JDK 10 API - couldn't find anything about this topic. [This is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.GetField.html) what I got.

Comment: Well, that link goes to `ObjectInputStream.GetField`. The question was about the native function `GetObjectField` which the JVM provides as part of its JNI implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, ["All Java objects returned by JNI functions are local references."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#global_and_local_references) You should call DeleteLocalRef on it or use the frame functions to manage local references.